# grid items within the parent grid are not undergoing horizontal resizing

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web dev world. Currently I'm struggling on how to horizontally resize all items inside my grid class `card` horizontally. I want that my class `.card__header, .card__info` will respect the `max-width: 500px` of my parent class `.card` even though I set both width to 100%. Using `min-width` is ok, but when I use `max-width` it only stuck at 320px even though I resize the screen to its max width. Also if I shrink it down the page, the content gets cut horizontally on the right side. Can you help me what is missing on my code? An explanation is much appreciated.

```css
/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}

/*
    Typographic tweaks!
    3. Add accessible line-height
    4. Improve text rendering
  */
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/*
    5. Improve media defaults
  */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/*
    6. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/*
    7. Avoid text overflows
  */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

/*
    8. Create a root stacking context
  */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

:root {
  /* Primary Colors */
  --clr--gradient: hsl(6, 100%, 80%) to hsl(335, 100%, 65%);
  /* Neutral Colors */
  --clr--pale-blue: hsl(243, 100%, 93%);
  --clr--grayish-blue: hsl(229, 7%, 55%);
  --clr--dark-blue: hsl(228, 56%, 26%);
  --clr--very-dark-blue: hsl(229, 57%, 11%);
}

:root {
  /* Font Family */
  --ff--primary: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  /* Font Size */
  --fs--regular: 14px;
  /* Font Weight */
  --fw--bold: 400;
  --fw--very-bold: 700;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

body {
  background: url("/images/bg-mobile.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: var(--clr--very-dark-blue);
  color: var(--clr--pale-blue);
  font-family: var(--ff--primary);
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.card__header, .card__info {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--clr--dark-blue);
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
}
.card__header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.card__header .logo img {
  width: 150px;
}
.card__header .flex-group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.card__header .flex-group li {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: var(--clr--very-dark-blue);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      sizes="32x32"
      href="./images/favicon-32x32.png"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css" class="css" />
    <title>Frontend Mentor | Fylo data storage component</title>

    <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
    <style>
      .attribution {
        font-size: 11px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .attribution a {
        color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <main class="card">
        <section class="card__header">
          <div class="logo">
            <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
          </div>
          <ul class="flex-group">
            <li><img src="/images/icon-document.svg" alt="Document" /></li>
            <li><img src="/images/icon-folder.svg" alt="Folder" /></li>
            <li><img src="/images/icon-upload.svg" alt="Upload" /></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="card__info">
          <p>You’ve used 815 GB of your storage</p>
          <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="815" />
          <div>185 GB LEFT</div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
    <footer class="attribution">
      Challenge by
      <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
        >Frontend Mentor</a
      >. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `max-width` only tells the element the maximum width it is allowed to be. It doesn't tell it that it must get that wide. It will only get that wide if there's enough content inside it to push it that wide. Currently, that's not the case.

Comment: Please clarify how the difference between how this snippet is rendering, and how you want it to render. Ideally you would do this by either editing your question to make it clearer, or editing the snippet to make it clearer, or both. It would also help to edit the snippet so that the image URLs point to images which are available on the internet.

Comment: @ralph.m, appreciate your response. How can I ensure that the width of my `.card__header, .card__info` class increases as the screen is resized?